# Unsure about definition Error

Tags: javascript

I'm given a big array and I then have to transfer the data to an a different array depending on if the type is "customer" "store"or "address" but I'm getting the following error and I;m not sure why

```
/*
Exception: ReferenceError: store is not defined
CustomerDB.insertData@Scratchpad/1:56:17
@Scratchpad/1:105:1
*/


var allData = [
{type:"store", data:{store_id: 297, name: "Scotiabank - Main Branch",     address_id: 1023}},
{type:"store", data:{store_id: 614, name: "Scotiabank - Hamilton",  address_id: 1984}},
{type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 24, store_id:614, first_name:  "Jonathan", last_name: "Pym", email: "jjpym@yahoo.ca", address_id: 1611, add_date: null}},
{type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 36, store_id:193, first_name: "Kaitlyn", last_name: "Adams", email: "katy38@hotmail.com", address_id: 5464, add_date: null}},
{type:"customer", data:{customer_id: 73, store_id:297, first_name: "Melissa", last_name: "Bennett", email: "mbennett@gmail.com", address_id: 4536, add_date: null}},        
{type:"address", data:{address_id: 1023, address: "2895 Yonge St.",     city:"Toronto", province:"ON", postal_code:"L4C02G"}},
{type:"address", data:{address_id: 1984, address: "3611 Main St. West", city:"Hamilton", province:"ON", postal_code:"R5O8H5"}},
{type:"address", data:{address_id: 1757, address: "1177 Ontario St. Unit 8", city:"Mississauga", province:"ON", postal_code:"L9H6B3"}},
{type:"address", data:{address_id: 4536, address: "3945 John St.", city: "Ajax", province: "ON", postal_code: "L7M4T9"}},

var CustomerDB =
{
    customer:[],
    address:[],
    store:[],

    insertData:function (allData)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++)
      {     
       if (allData[i].type == "store")
          {
            store[i].push(allData[i].store_id, allData[i].name, allData[i].address_id);

          }
        else if (allData[i].type == "customer")
          {
            this[i].add_date = new Date();
            customer[i].push(allData[i].customer_id, allData[i].store_id, allData[i].first_name, allData[i].last_name, allData[i].email, allData[i].addess_id, allData[i].add_date);
          }
        else if (allData[i].type == "address")
          {
            address[i].push(allData[i].address_id, allData[i].address, allData[i].city, allData[i].province, allData[i].cpostal_code);
          }
      }
    }
}
CustomerDB.insertData(allData);
```

Comment: I have a feeling I answered the same question somewhere else!

Comment: Its a different error,

Comment: Here the same exact question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181981/adding-elements-from-one-array-to-another/42182030#42182030

Comment: Like I used that and did a print statement to see how many elements were in each array and it came out empty so I'm answering it a different way, hence the new error

Comment: **Déjà vu**! Right??

Comment: Why not pushing the object?

Answer (score 0):

Although I still think https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182030/6647153 is the best answer. But here you go:

1. **THIS IS THE MAJOR PROBLEM**: You'll have to use the `this` keyword to access the property (array) `store`, `cutomer` and `adress`.
2. When pushing to an array, you don't need to use subscripts.
3. You'll have to wrap your data inside an object to keep things grouped. (Here I used the original object)

Try this:

```
insertData: function (allData) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {     
        if (allData[i].type == "store") {
            this.store.push(allData[i]);
        }
        else if (allData[i].type == "customer") {
            allData[i].add_date = new Date();
            this.customer.push(allData[i]);
        }
        else if (allData[i].type == "address") {
            this.adress(allData[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to copy the object and not pushing the original, then use this function like this:

```
function clone(obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    for(var key in obj)
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    return newObj;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
insertData: function (allData) {
    for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) { 
        var o = clone(allData[i]);
        var type = o.type;
        delete o.type; // to remove the type if you want
        if (type == "store") {
            this.store.push(o);
        }
        else if (type == "customer") {
            var o.add_date = new Date();
            this.customer.push(o);
        }
        else if (type == "address") {
            this.adress(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for being patient. The reason I didn't want to use your other method was that I haven't learned that yet and so I don't just want to take someone elses code and put it into mine just because it worked. I wanted to come up with my own solution and execute it and fix any errors I find because that's how I learn best. :) PS, I think you forgot a .push when pushing the address

Comment: Your thoroughness is very much appreciated

Comment: @WorkMan Here is the docs for `this` on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)! Check the section [**As an object method**]!

Comment: @WorkMan and here is a great online book. I think you'll find it useful! http://eloquentjavascript.net/